# Crash base.apk in crashlytics android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics

My application exists as a C++ module (JNI architecture) and Java module.
I have a problem when I release a new version of my android app. 
There are many crashes and missing lines from base.apk which I have never encountered before.
I don't know where the bug is coming from (your code or anything else ?).
Stack trace in fabric crashlytics below.
Thanks to all of you.

```
Crashed: Thread
0  base.apk                       0xcee52642 (Missing)
1  base.apk                       0xcee5ab31 (Missing)
2  base.apk                       0xcee56e01 (Missing)
3  base.apk                       0xcee57eab (Missing)
4  base.apk                       0xcee3d305 (Missing)
5  libc.so                        0xf59c3a9b (Missing)
6  libc.so                        0xf5a1b406 (Missing)
7  libc.so                        0xf5a0b1cf (Missing)
8  libc.so                        0xf59fcaef (Missing)
9  base.apk                       0xcee477b7 (Missing)
10 base.apk                       0xcee4907f (Missing)
11 base.apk                       0xcee5ab3d (Missing)
12 base.apk                       0xcee56f43 (Missing)
13 base.apk                       0xcee5aaff (Missing)
14 libandroid_runtime.so          0xf42179e4 (Missing)
15 (Missing)                      0x12dfbe1e (Missing)
16 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746ba1cb (Missing)
17 (Missing)                      0x707670de (Missing)
18 (Missing)                      0x7019f11e (Missing)
19 (Missing)                      0x12dfbe1e (Missing)
20 (Missing)                      0x13329a9e (Missing)
21 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746bc661 (Missing)
22 (Missing)                      0x7076792a (Missing)
23 (Missing)                      0x7020cafe (Missing)
24 (Missing)                      0x7059a21a (Missing)
25 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
26 (Missing)                      0x13329a9e (Missing)
27 (Missing)                      0x12dfbe1e (Missing)
28 (Missing)                      0x13288926 (Missing)
29 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
30 system@framework@boot.oat      0x7465d88d (Missing)
31 (Missing)                      0x7059b04e (Missing)
32 (Missing)                      0x130bebfe (Missing)
33 (Missing)                      0x705a103a (Missing)
34 (Missing)                      0x12e3a3fe (Missing)
35 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746a23d5 (Missing)
36 (Missing)                      0x705a103a (Missing)
37 (Missing)                      0x131631c6 (Missing)
38 system@framework@boot.oat      0x74638d41 (Missing)
39 libc.so                        0xf59f7027 (Missing)
40 (Missing)                      0x13154bee (Missing)
41 (Missing)                      0x12d0d04e (Missing)
42 (Missing)                      0x130bebfe (Missing)
43 libc.so                        0xf5a04331 (Missing)
44 (Missing)                      0x12d0d04e (Missing)
45 (Missing)                      0x70598ae6 (Missing)
46 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746614ef (Missing)
47 (Missing)                      0x7059c686 (Missing)
48 (Missing)                      0x13288926 (Missing)
49 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
50 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746605f3 (Missing)
51 (Missing)                      0x7059c07a (Missing)
52 (Missing)                      0x12e3a3fe (Missing)
53 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
54 (Missing)                      0x13288926 (Missing)
55 (Missing)                      0x130bebfe (Missing)
56 (Missing)                      0x12e3a3fe (Missing)
57 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
58 system@framework@boot.oat      0x74660393 (Missing)
59 (Missing)                      0x7059c00e (Missing)
60 (Missing)                      0x70585b62 (Missing)
61 (Missing)                      0x12e3a7fe (Missing)
62 system@framework@boot.oat      0x746601fb (Missing)
63 (Missing)                      0x7059bfa2 (Missing)
```

Comment: Hey, Paul from Crashlytics here. This question will most likely require more information and a back-and-forth exchange to answer, and would be better suited for our support channel. Please reach out to us at support(at)fabric(dot)io. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @buser, I don't think it is bug of fabric system. Because I have never encountered it for old version. Missing line because some external lib which I used,  I don't have source code. I think about What I missing when I build apk.

Comment: @huynguyen are you able to fix the issue, i am having same issue with Crashlytics